# Large grey bird at creek mouth (east of Toronto)

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

What species of bird is this?

- Spotted at the mouth of [Graham Creek at Newcastle Marina (Bond Head)](https://goo.gl/maps/kXCxzmmXkFZD1V1i6), Lake Ontario, Canada
- September 9, 2023
- The bird was roughly 18 inches tall; dark grey body; light grey head and neck; yellow beak

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for precise location. Sometimes questions here include vague locations (e.g. Canada) or no location at all, nor even a hint on the habitat, and location is often useful to discard a lot of species.

Comment: The second picture is very good (both for identification and the moment)

Answer (score 21):

I'm highly confident that this is a cormorant. I'm less certain of the species, but based on the location I would bet that it is a [double-crested cormorant](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Double-crested_Cormorant/id) (perhaps a juvenile based on the head color/feathering, though I don't know if this varies in adults based on season) as these are found in high numbers around the Great Lakes region, including Lake Ontario.

[image: Double-crested cormorant juvenile]  photo by Jane Mann, from [Macaulay Library](https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/49723871)

See also:

[The rise of the Double-crested Cormorant on the Great Lakes:
WINNING THE WAR AGAINST CONTAMINANTS](https://ontarionature.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/En40-222-2-1995E.pdf)

Comment: Looking at the maps in my Sibley guide, there are occasionally vagrant Great Cormorants & Anhingas in the Great Lakes area.  But their coloration is different, even for the juveniles, and so I agree that it's far, far more likely to be a Double-Crested Cormorant

Comment: Anhinga can be ruled out by the bill; theirs is straight, without the hook at the end cormorants have.

Answer (score 0):

A cormorant or possibly a shag. Far more common in saltwater surroundings, but can be at home in fresh water.

Comment: As mentioned by @BryanKrause, cormorants are super-common around Lake Ontario, e.g. this photo from Hamilton harbour https://ontariohunting.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/3-0_Super_Portrait.jpg (source: https://ontariohunting.net/nature-not-bullets-should-control-cormorants-mcmaster-biologist-says/ )

Comment: @BenBolker - Coming from UK, I wouldn't have a clue about that! But thanks anyhow.